# perl script not extracting only path (regex)

Tags: regex, perl

I have this regex expression

```
($oldpath = $_) =~ m/^\/(.+\/)*/;
```

This is the input:

```
/cd-lib/mp3/rock/LittleFeat/Dixie_Chicken/110-lafayette_railroad.mp3
```

But the output is:

```
/cd-lib/mp3/rock/LittleFeat/Dixie_Chicken/110-lafayette_railroad.mp3
```

When it should be:

```
/cd-lib/mp3/rock/LittleFeat/Dixie_Chicken/
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: See [this Perl demo](https://ideone.com/hDfGPt) or [this one](https://ideone.com/2KzE6u).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I get what i did wrong now. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "output"? `$1` contains

```
cd-lib/mp3/rock/LittleFeat/Dixie_Chicken/
```

which is almost what you wanted (it just misses the leading `/`).

You assigned `$_` to `$oldpath`, than matched it against a regex. It doesn't change either `$_` or `$oldpath`.

The canonical way is

```
my ($match) = m/^\/(.+\/)*/;
```

or rather (to prevent the leaning toothpick syndrome)

```
my ($match) = m{^/(.+/)*};
```

i.e. running the match in list context returns the matching capture groups, and the first one is assinged to $match.

Comment: why not given the suggestion for `File::basename`. There is any particular reason champ.